# URL re-writing problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this below code to re-write URL :

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^buynow/(.*)$ Model/Public/BuyNow/buynow.php?str=$1&f=$2   [L]
```

But as in these lines,Second parameter `"f"` is not working here.I have searched on google but not getting result.Kindly give your suggestions

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `f` should contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one group (delimited by `(` ... `)`) in your regular expression. `$1` refers to what was matched in this group, and `$2` refers to what was matched in a second group, which doesn't exist. Because there is no second group, `$2` will always evaluate to `""`.

What part of the URL is `f` supposed to represent?

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, it would seem the rule should look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^buynow[^/]*/(.*)/([^/]*)$ Model/Public/BuyNow/buynow.php?str=$1&f=$2   [L]
```

Comment: How I can edit this code:RewriteRule ^buynow/(.*)$ Model/Public/BuyNow/buynow.php?str=$1&f=$2

Comment: @Deepak: You'll need to show us a sample URL, and indicate which part of the URL `f` should be set to in order for us to know how to fix the rule

Comment: see this url which i need to rewrite in other way

Answer (score 1):

You are only capturing one string, so there is no `$2` corresponding to a second capture group.

Answer (score 0):

The Rule you wrote supports the passing of **1** parameter only, the ^buynow/**(.*)**$ is one parameter which is not broken into 2, therefore your expected parameter will never arrive.
Please post an example of the original URL so I can help you to resolve the issue.